# Shape change events in Excel C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, add-in

I am writing an Excel Add-in which is rendered as a task pane on right and left part of an Excel sheet.
On the right hand task pane, I have added a treeview and I drag a node inside the Excel sheet.

When this node is dragged into Worksheet, I get the SheetChange event.

In this event, I add a Shape: worksheetReport.Shapes.AddShape

What I want to do now is to also get the Shape change events. The Shape can be changed for height, width and position.

I get the SheetSelectionChange when a cell is clicked after the Shape is resized. But I dont have one to one association of Shape change and event.

Any other workaround for this problem?

Regards,
Mayur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no events.

I have to rely on Sheet_Change event.